# How to get currecny format values using regex jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I have html content it contain so many elements and also some currency values like 
9,999 , 10,999,24,45,566,1,89,999 etc. I have to get only these values using regular expression on loading page.

Below is sample code,

```
 <ul class="upgradePlan mT20 poRel ">
         <li class="monthRow yrRow cf replacerow">
          <div class="desc"><h1>Yearly <span><b>Savings</b> Plan</span></h1></div>
           <div class="freeCol  poRel">
             <h1 class="pepstart">INR<span>9,999</span></h1> 
             <p class="svng"><!-- Save 26% --></p>
             <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
             <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn mt3" data-form="payment" data-param="2" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
           <div class="proCol  poRel">
             <h1 class="peppro">INR<span>14,999</span></h1> 
             <p class="svng"><!-- Save 26% --></p>
             <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
             <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="3" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
           <div class="cstClr  poRel"><span class="cstM">
             <h1 class="pepultima">INR<span>44,999</span></h1> 
             <p class="svng"><!-- Save 44% --></p>
             <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
           <p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="4" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
         </li>



         <li class="row cf">
           <div class="desc"><h6>Google Adwords</h6></div>
           <div class="freeCol"><p>No</p></div>
           <div class="proCol proAdwords"><p>INR 1,000</p></div>
           <div class="cstClr ultimaAdwords"><p>INR 2,500</p></div>
         </li>

         <li class="row twolBr cf">
           <div class="desc"><h6>Pepads</h6></div>
           <div class="freeCol freePepads"><p>INR 2,500</p></div>
           <div class="proCol proPepads"><p>INR 7,500</p></div>
           <div class="cstClr ultimaPepads"><p>INR 20,000</p></div>
         </li>


        </ul>
```

Comment: because I want dynamically so .

Comment: With the given HTML markup you can do "dynamically" without regex

Comment: I want to match only currecny values with regex. Like $(li).each(function(){ var regex = "";var matches = $(this).html().match(regex);  });

Answer (score 0):

Check your console, without regex.

```js
$('div.poRel h1 > span').each(function(element){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="monthRow yrRow cf replacerow">
              <div class="desc"><h1>Yearly <span><b>Savings</b> Plan</span></h1></div>
               <div class="freeCol  poRel">
                 <h1 class="pepstart">INR<span>9,999</span></h1> 
                 <p class="svng"><!-- Save 26% --></p>
                 <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
                 <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn mt3" data-form="payment" data-param="2" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
               <div class="proCol  poRel">
                 <h1 class="peppro">INR<span>14,999</span></h1> 
                 <p class="svng"><!-- Save 26% --></p>
                 <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
                 <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="3" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
               <div class="cstClr  poRel"><span class="cstM">
                 <h1 class="pepultima">INR<span>44,999</span></h1> 
                 <p class="svng"><!-- Save 44% --></p>
                 <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
               <p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="4" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
             </li>
```

Comment: I want to it using regex beacuse it may contain more li's without classes so I want make it dynamically not manually like using selector.

Comment: @Mohakumar is the value always in `<span>` in `<h1>` ?

Comment: it can be like <p> in <div>

Comment: @Mohakumar that's no where visible in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the spans and get the numbers using `/[\d\.]+/g` regex :

```
$('span').each(function(element) {
    $(this).text().match(/[\d\.]+/g);
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('span').each(function(element) {
  var num = $(this).text().match(/[\d\.]+/g);
  
  if (num != null) {
    var number = num.toString();
    console.log(number);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="monthRow yrRow cf replacerow">
  <div class="desc">
    <h1>Yearly <span><b>Savings</b> Plan</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="freeCol  poRel">
    <h1 class="pepstart">INR<span>9,999</span></h1>
    <p class="svng">
      <!-- Save 26% -->
    </p>
    <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
    <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn mt3" data-form="payment" data-param="2" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
  <div class="proCol  poRel">
    <h1 class="peppro">INR<span>14,999</span></h1>
    <p class="svng">
      <!-- Save 26% -->
    </p>
    <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
    <span class="proM"><p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="3" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p></span></div>
  <div class="cstClr  poRel"><span class="cstM">
                 <h1 class="pepultima">INR<span>44,999</span></h1>
    <p class="svng">
      <!-- Save 44% -->
    </p>
    <p class="bldAnvl">Billed Annually</p>
    <p class="opt"><a class="connect premiumBtn" data-form="payment" data-param="4" data-index="19" href="javascript:;">Start Now</a></p>
    </span>
  </div>
</li>
```